# a program which identifies the differences between pairs of strings

Tags: java, string, compare, character

My problem is that I need to identify characters which differ between the two given strings in a visually striking way. Output the two input strings on two lines, and then identify the differences on the line below using periods (for identical characters) and asterisks (for differing characters). For example:

```
ATCCGCTTAGAGGGATT
GTCCGTTTAGAAGGTTT
*....*.....*..*..
```

I have tried to write two string with each other but I dont know how to make the program check for every character in the string and see if those match

This is what I have done so far :/

```
System.out.println("String 1: ");
String var1 = Scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("String 2: ");
String var2 = Scanner.nextLine();

if (same (var1, var2))
    System.out.println(".........");
else
    System.out.println("********");

public static boolean same (String var1, String var2){
    if (var1.equals(var2))
    {
        return true;        
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please edit the question and show what you've tried.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GajaneYan Please edit your question, don't post code in comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through your Strings and compare characters one by one. To run through your list you can make a for-loop. Use an int as counter and use the method [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()) to obtain your string size.

```
for(int i=0; i<string1.length(); i++ {
    // do stuff
}
```

Then since you have a counter going through all position of your string, you can obtain the character at a specific position in this string using the method [`charAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))

```
char char1 = string1.charAt(i);
```

Then compare the character to check if they are the same. If they are print a dot `.` if they're not print an asterisk `*`

```
if(char1 == char2) {
    System.out.print(".");
} else {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

---

In the above part I supposed your two string have the same size. If it's not the case, you can first determine which one is the smallest (and so which is the biggest) :

```
String smallestString;
String biggestString;
if(string1.size() > string2.sise()) {
     smallestString = string2;
     biggestString = string1;
else { 
     smallestString = string1;
     biggestString = string2;
}
```

Then make your for loop go through the smallest String, otherwise you will face [IndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

```
for(int i=0; i<smallestString.length(); i++ {
    // do stuff
}
```

And the end of this for loop print asterisks for the characters that left in the biggest String

```
for(int j=smallestString.length(); j<biggestString.length(); j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to see if I can make it from here :D

Answer (score -1):

This is what I've come up with.Mind you there are better ways to do this and I've just written it with as much effort as you put in your question.

```
public class AskBetterQuestion{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String w1="ATCCGCTTAGAGGGATT";
        String w2="GTCCGTTTAGAAGGTTT";


        char[] first  = w1.toCharArray();
        char[] second = w2.toCharArray();

        int minLength = Math.min(first.length, second.length);
        char[] out=new char[minLength];

        for(int i = 0; i < minLength; i++)
        {
                if (first[i] != second[i])
                {
                    out[i]='.';
                }
                else out[i]='*';
        }

            System.out.println(w1);
            System.out.println(w2);
            System.out.print(out);

    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new here and I had problems with posting the code, thank you so much I will try to see if I can fix it from here :)